# AMD T14 Gen 3 Dying After Sleep

Tags: thinkpad, amd-processor

When shutting and reopening the lid of my T14, my computer dies. The Esc, F4, and power lights are all on, but the keyboard does not respond to any input. Pressing the Caps Lock key does not result in the light turning on. The screen is blank. When this happens, I have to hold the power button down to force restart the entire system.
Would anybody happen to know a fix for this? I read something about a BIOS update that should have fixed it, but mine is already version w60, while the fix they were referring to apparently should have shipped with w54.

Currently running Ubuntu 20.04 on a ThinkPad T14 Gen 3 with an AMD processor.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** What version of the Ubuntu OS are you running? Also, please include both the make and model of your laptop (e.g., Lenovo T14 Gen 3) in your question so it'll be easier for others to find this question in the future if they encounter the same issues. Thanks